# How to get rid of youtube html5 player from firefox

Tags: 12.04, firefox, flash, youtube, html5

I have tried youtube html5 player by opting it in from [here](http://www.youtube.com/html5)
But i dont find html5 youtube player as good as flash player. 
So i opted out from same link despite of opt-out youtube was showing videos in HTML5.
I tried

- Deleting Cookies
- Deleting firefox profile
- Deleting .mozila directory from home
- Uninstalling and reinstalling firefox

But still problem persist and it is really annoying. Meanwhile i installed chrome and i am getting flash player in chrome but no luck in firefox. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution just download an app called (YouTube™ Flash® Player) from the firefox store It will automatically/force youtube to play with flash player not HTML5.

Comment: You have to install the add-on as youtube now forces HTML5 player on us (firefox versions 36 and above, iirc)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I personally use and I believe works for Firefox as well ( I use Chromium)

Install the Greasemonkey extension and use this script

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/114002

It's called "Youtube Center"

It integrates into the Youtube site and gives you options to disable auto-play, force a predeterimined resolution and choose which player to force, HTML5 or Flash.

Answer (score 0):

installing adobe flash plug-in worked for me: ether install it from Ubuntu software center or by going to a terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and copy pasting this to it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Note: the adobe flash plug-in is not updated for Ubuntu as it's for windows, if you can live with that install it.